# javascript video custom controls

Tags: javascript, css, html, video

I get stuck with making the video responsive with custom controls.

I know how to make the video responsive, with a `<figure></figure>` element and the width on 100% the video is responsive, and that's great! But the thing is, the progress bar isn't responsive. Because it is calculated with the width of the video itself.

I don't want to post my whole code because it will be to long for this post. But I can give the link where I got it from. [This is the link if you are interested.](http://www.inserthtml.com/2013/03/custom-html5-video-player/)

The code where it all happens is this:

```
// Width of the video
$videoWidth = $this.width();
$that.width($videoWidth + 'px');

//Set width of the player based on previously noted settings
$that.find('.player').css({
    'width': ($settings.playerWidth * 100) + '%',
    'left': ((100 - $settings.playerWidth * 100) / 2) + '%'
});
```

It gives the div a inline width px, but if you want a responsive page you don't want to do that. But I am not that experienced how to solve this.. So I hope that someone can help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, already fixed it by myself! 
If you are curious, this is the right solution.

```
// Width of the video
//$videoWidth = $this.width();
//$that.width($videoWidth + 'px');

//Set width of the player based on previously noted settings
$that.find('.progress').css({
'width': ($settings.playerWidth * 100) + '%',
//'left': ((100 - $settings.playerWidth * 100) / 2) + '%'
});
```

Ultimately it turns out that almost everything could be gone away and you only need to change the class of the css.